# Painting color and normals simultaneously

Tags: texturing, materials, normals, masking

**It seems this question is unresolved :**
If I want to paint let’s say wood color and normals on a part of my mesh, how would I do that?
Painting it once for each layer (color then normals) will produce a mismatch between the texture coordinates.
It’s important to keep the whole model on one material (of course normals and metallic are on separate textures) because I’ll use it for a game, so need to keep the draw calls at minimum.

**Consider this scene : should I make one material per substance, or should I make only one texture containing wood, paint, ceiling, etc.** Because then I won't just sculpt the wood details and bake them right?** :
[image]

I just can’t get it right, been looking for that solution for years.
Is ArmorPaint supposed to do that?

Thank you very much !

Comment: what is the problem if you convert your color painting into a normal map (with a software like CrazyBump or else)? it will take the values into account and the 2 images will match

Comment: Well it's acceptable as a solution but when the normal differ from the color (imagine marble), it doesn't match and you have to edit it out or something.
So I'm looking for a professional workflow if there is one...
But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Maybe pictures relaying what you are trying to emulate here could help - as far as  workflow I mean. I have a simple method of getting detail into a normal map by using texture paint to color and baking a sculpt version with hires copy to get my normal since they have the same UV map.

Comment: Hi, I updated the post. In the case I want to add wood, I won't just sculpt all the repetitive wood details on a hires right?